# Ajax request works with older versions of jquery not new

Tags: jquery, ajax

I updated jquery to a newer version in an old file that was having some new features added. Now the jquery ajax post has stopped working. I have tried changing success to done but this did not sort the problem.

```
// check email in database
$("#email_address").change(function () //this function needs tidying up!
{ //if theres a change in the email textbox

    var email_address = $("#email_address").val(); //Get the value in the username textbox
    if (email_address.length > 3) //if the lenght greater than 3 characters
    {
        $("#availability_status").html('<img src="../img/loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> Checking this email is not already registered<br />'); //Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"

        $.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
            type: "POST",
            url: "../ajax_check_email.php", //file name
            data: "email_address=" + email_address, //data
            success: function (server_response) {

                $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function (event, request) {

                    if (server_response == '0') //if ajax_check_email.php return value "0"
                    {
                        $("#availability_status").css("display", "none");
                    } else if (server_response == '1') //if it returns "1"
                    {
                        $("#availability_status").css("display", "inline");
                        $("#availability_status").html('<font color="red">This email address is already registered in our database. </font>');
                    }

                });
            }

        });

    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's this:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/:

***"As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document."***

However, I'm not sure why that is there to begin with. You should be able to remove the `ajaxComplete` part entirely:

```
success: function (server_response) {

    if (server_response == '0') //if ajax_check_email.php return value "0"
    {
        $("#availability_status").css("display", "none");
    } else if (server_response == '1') //if it returns "1"
    {
        $("#availability_status").css("display", "inline");
        $("#availability_status").html('<font color="red">This email address is already registered in our database. </font>');
    }

}
```

Comment: I completely removed the .ajaxComplete() and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

should it be enough:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.8, the `.ajaxComplete()` method should only be attached to document, like:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    // do something on complete
});
```

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

You have an `ajaxComplete()` method inside your AJAX request. Can you not use the `complete()` callback like your `success()` callback?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ajax_check_email.php", //file name
    data: "email_address=" + email_address, //data
    success: function() {
        // do something
    },
    complete: function() {
        // do something
    }
});
```